# TikZ: drawing balancing diagrams like SolveMe Mobiles

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, node-connections

I want to draw a diagram like this:

[image: Puzzle #11]

In general, the diagrams in [SolveMe Mobiles](http://solveme.edc.org/Mobiles.html) (section Play)

I suppose I can do with raw code, but I want to do with custom command like: "make horizontal line", "put a hexagonal node", and so on. Is it possible?

**Edit :**

This is the "raw code" answer, but it's NOT modular:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[edge from parent fork down]
  \node{\space}
    child {node [draw, fill=green!20,rectangle] {\space}
        child {node [draw, fill=green!20,rectangle] {\space}}
      }
    child {node [draw, fill=blue!20,circle] {\space}
      child {node [draw, fill=yellow!20] {\space}}
      child {node [draw, fill=red!20] {\space}}
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

It gives me this[image]

which is far away from what I want.

Comment: What do you mean with "raw code"? If you mean PGF/TikZ code, maybe that "raw code" can solve your problem in a easier way than you expect.

Comment: I think it surely is possible. Can you show us how you've started to solve the problem? Even just the lines representing the hanger and bar would be a good start. Please post it here if you have tried! :-)

Comment: I guess it is essentially a tree so you could use the `trees` library or `tikz-qtree` or `forest` or the `graphs` library or something like that.

Comment: With "raw code" I mean using TikZ without any specific library (eg. tree library)

Comment: You can create pics for the basic building blocks.  But unlike nodes, pics do not have anchors, just origins.

Comment: What do you mean by 'modular' exactly? How would you like it to work, ideally? It would be helpful, too, if you would complete your example as that is much more useful than a mere code fragment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your picture is (to me) more easily to draw without use of trees library:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning,
                shadows,
                shapes.geometric
                }

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm and 11mm,
    start chain = going below,
           font = \sffamily,
   basic/.style = {shape=regular polygon, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=1ex, 
                   node contents={~~},  on chain},
     hex/.style = {basic,regular polygon sides=6,
                   top color=teal!30, bottom color=teal!90},
     tri/.style = {basic,regular polygon sides=3,
                   top color=purple!30, bottom color=purple!90,
                   shape border rotate=-180, inner sep=2pt},
     pet/.style = {basic,regular polygon sides=5,
                   top color=orange!30, bottom color=orange!90},
                    ]
\coordinate[left =of {(0,0)}]    (a);
\coordinate[right=of {(0,0)}]    (b);
%
\node (a1) [hex,below=of a];
\node (a2) [hex];
\node (a3) [hex];
    \node (a4) [tri,below=of a3];
    \node[right=0mm of a4.east] {=12};
%
\node (b1) [pet,below=of b];
\node (b2) [tri];
%
\node (c) [hex,left=of a4.west];
\node[right=0mm of c.east] {=5};
        \node (d) [pet,right=of a4.east];
        \node[right] at (d.east) {$=$};
        \node[draw=gray,text width=2em,minimum height=4ex,
              right=5 mm of d.east] {};
% lines
\draw[gray,thick]  (0,0) -- + (0,7mm);
\draw[ultra thick,cap=round] (a) -- (b);
\draw[gray] (a) -- (a1) (a1) -- (a2)    (a2) -- (a3)
            (b) -- (b1) (b1) -- (b2);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Where I use pentagon instead of heart. It can be drawn by `pic`, however for the first approximation of desired picture should pentagon suffice:

[image]

**Upgrade:** in case dat you very desired to have hearth instead pentagon, than you can drawe heart with `pic`. With this small pictures a bit more effort is needed for its placements in picture:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{chains,
                positioning,
                shadows,
                shapes.geometric
                }

    \begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance=5mm and 13mm,
    start chain = going below,
           font = \sffamily,
   basic/.style = {shape=regular polygon, outer sep=0pt, minimum size=1ex, 
                   node contents={~~},  on chain},
     hex/.style = {basic,regular polygon sides=6,
                   top color=teal!30, bottom color=teal!90},
     tri/.style = {basic,regular polygon sides=3,
                   top color=purple!30, bottom color=purple!90,
                   shape border rotate=-180, inner sep=2pt},
       pet/.pic = {\path[top color=orange!30, bottom color=orange!90]
                    (0,0)   .. controls (0.0,0.15) and (-0.3,0.20) .. (-0.3,0.4)
                        arc (180:0:0.15)
                        arc (180:0:0.15)
                            .. controls (0.3,0.20) and ( 0.0,0.15) .. (0,0);
                    \coordinate (-south)    at (0,0.02);
                    \coordinate (-north)    at (0,0.4);
                    \coordinate (-west)     at (-0.2,0.3);
                    \coordinate (-center)   at (0,0.3);
                    \coordinate (-east)     at (+0.2,0.3);}
%     pet/.style = {basic,regular polygon sides=5,
%                   top color=orange!30, bottom color=orange!90},
                    ]
\coordinate[left =of {(0,0)}]    (a);
\coordinate[right=of {(0,0)}]    (b);
%
\node (a1) [hex,below=of a];
\node (a2) [hex];
\node (a3) [hex];
    \node (a4) [tri,below=of a3];
    \node[right=0mm of a4.east] {=12};
%
\pic[below=of a1 -| b]  (b1)  {pet};
\node (b2) [tri,below=of b1-south];
%
\node (c) [hex,left=of a4.west];
\node[right=0mm of c.east] {=5};
        \pic [right=17mm of a4.south]  (d) {pet};
        \node[right] at (d-east) {$=$};
        \node[draw=gray,text width=2em,minimum height=4ex,
              right=5 mm of d-east] {};
% lines
\draw[gray,thick]  (0,0) -- + (0,7mm);
\draw[ultra thick,cap=round] (a) -- (b);
\draw[gray] (a) -- (a1) (a1) -- (a2)    (a2) -- (a3)
            (b) -- (b1-north) (b1-south) -- (b2);

    \end{document}
```

And now the pictures is:

[image]

Comment: thanks. This is exactly what I want: modular design. You just put [hex] and all comes after... ;)

Answer (score 4):

Just using simple stacks.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{marvosym,amssymb,txfonts,stackengine,xcolor,scalerel}
\def\hex{\kern.2pt\textcolor{green!80!black}{\scalerel*{$\Hexasteel$}{)}}}
\def\btd{\textcolor{blue!30!red}{\scalerel*{\blacktriangledown}{)}}}
\def\hrt{\textcolor{orange!80!red}{\scalerel*{\varheartsuit}{)}}}
\def\topstik{\rule{1pt}{10pt}}
\def\stik{\rule{1pt}{5pt}}
\def\hbar{\rule{2.5em}{2pt}}
\setstackgap{S}{-.2pt}
\setstackEOL{\cr}
\begin{document}
\stackunder[15pt]{%
  \stackunder{\Shortstack{\topstik\cr\hbar}}{%
    \Shortunderstack{\topstik\cr\hex\cr\stik\cr\hex\cr\stik\cr\hex}%
    \quad%
    \Shortunderstack{\topstik\cr\hrt\cr\stik\cr\btd}%
  }%
}{%
  $\hex=5\quad\btd=12\quad\hrt=\fbox{\strut~~~~~}$%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]